# Obtener parametro de xml en clase no servlet en java

Tags: java, xml

como puedo obtener el valor de un parámetro de un xml en una clase no servlet en java ??

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>passcorreo</param-name>
        <param-value>********</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Obtener el valor de passcorreo, lo echo en servlet asi

```
ServletContext contexto = request.getServletContext();
String passcorreo = contexto.getInitParameter("passcorreo");
```

pero como puedo hacerlo en una clase NO SERVLET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de utilizar context-param, utiliza env-entry en tu XML:

```
<env-entry> 
    <description>Mi pwd</description>
    <env-entry-name>passcorreo</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>tuPassword</env-entry-value> 
</env-entry>
```

Y para acceder a ella:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

Context cntxt= new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
String password= (String)cntxt.lookup("passcorreo");
```

Referencia:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1662707.html

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió super bien